# Group array of data by all available keys

Tags: javascript, nestjs, prisma

I'm developing an application in NestJS/Prisma and am a little bit stuck here.

I basically need to bring all unique results from a table, to show it in a filter in the front-end.

To better understand my structure, I have a table called `People`, and this table contains general information about people such as name, country, preferred language, profile type, department, etc.

I need to query the database and bring all unique (distinct) results from certain fields.

Currently, I get distinct results by running the following query:

```js
const contentFromDatabase = await this.prisma.people.groupBy({
     by: ['profileType', 'preferredLanguage', 'department'],
});
```

And it returns me an array like this:

```json
[
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Automotive"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "student",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Baby"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "business",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Beauty"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Books"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "business",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Clothing"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "business",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Computers"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "business",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Electronics"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Games"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "student",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Garden"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "student",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Grocery"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Health"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "business",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Home"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Industrial"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "business",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Jewelery"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Kids"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "business",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Movies"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Music"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Outdoors"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Shoes"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Sports"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Tools"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "business",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Toys"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Automotive"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "business",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Baby"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Beauty"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Books"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Clothing"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "student",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Computers"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Electronics"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Games"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Garden"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "student",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Grocery"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Health"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Home"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Industrial"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Jewelery"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Kids"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Movies"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Music"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Outdoors"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Shoes"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "business",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Sports"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Tools"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "business",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Toys"
    }
]
```

But in the reality, what I want is something like this:

```json
{
    "profileType": [
        "business", "professor", "student"
    ],
    "preferredLanguage": [
        "en", "fr"
    ],
    "department": [
        "Automotive", "Books", "Garden", "Health", "Games", "Sports", "Shoes", "Grocery", "Tools", "Music", "Kids", "Industrial", "Home", "Beauty", "Computers", "Movies", "Toys", "Outdoors", "Jewelery", "Electronics", "Baby", "Clothing"
    ]
}
```

As I believe it's not possible to achieve it using a database only, I was trying to create a function to solve it, but I failed miserably!

##### Good to know:

Things to consider:

- Right now I'm using single arrays, but I might use associative arrays in the future.
- In the example above I'm using only 3 fields to group by, but it will probably be dynamically, changing according to necessity.
- The reason for this function, is that my client wants the filters to be populated with data already existing in the database.

  - E.g.: In the field country, instead of showing 200+, I need to show only the ones that the users have registered in my database.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I played around with this, you can create a function wrapping the below logic, here `inp` is the array that you get from prisma.

```js
let inp = [
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Automotive"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "student",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Baby"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "business",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Beauty"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Books"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "business",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Clothing"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "business",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Computers"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "business",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Electronics"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Games"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "student",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Garden"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "student",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Grocery"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Health"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "business",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Home"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Industrial"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "business",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Jewelery"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Kids"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "business",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Movies"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Music"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Outdoors"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Shoes"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Sports"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Tools"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "business",
        "preferredLanguage": "en",
        "department": "Toys"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Automotive"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "business",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Baby"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Beauty"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Books"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Clothing"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "student",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Computers"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Electronics"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Games"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Garden"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "student",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Grocery"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Health"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Home"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Industrial"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Jewelery"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Kids"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Movies"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Music"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Outdoors"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Shoes"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "business",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Sports"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "professor",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Tools"
    },
    {
        "profileType": "business",
        "preferredLanguage": "fr",
        "department": "Toys"
    }
];


/**
 * function to create the initial container object
 * which has properties corresponding to the input array
 * @returns the newly created object
 */
const createInitialObj = () => {
  const obj = {};
  Object.keys(inp[0]).forEach(key => {
    // set is used to offset the duplicate items
    obj[key] = new Set();
  });
  return obj;
}

// get the corresponding properties from input array and populate initial object accordingly.
inp = inp.reduce((acc, item) => {
  for (const props in item) {
    acc[props].add(item[props])
  }
  return acc;
}, createInitialObj());

// convert set to array
for (const props in inp) {
  inp[props] = Array.from(inp[props]);
}

console.log(inp);
```

This solution would work for dynamic properties.